# Energy minimization doesn't seem to yield a geodesic

Tags: differential-geometry, fisher-information, information-geometry

I'm minimizing (through optimization using gradient descent) the energy $E(\gamma)=\int_{t_1}^{t_2} g_{\alpha\beta}(\gamma^{\alpha})'(\gamma^{\beta})'\operatorname{d}\!t$ of a curve using the inner product induced by the metric tensor. In my case the metric tensor is from information geometry (the Fisher metric) which is very simple for a univariate gaussian.

However, given that I'm using the [Fisher metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher_information_metric) as the metric tensor, I would expect that a geodesic of a univariate gaussian to follow an arc (e.g. shortest path between two univariate gaussian distributions is not a straight line [as shown here](https://geomstats.github.io/notebooks/08_practical_methods__information_geometry.html)). However, after optimizing the curve to minimize the energy, I'm always getting a straight line as distance between two univariate gaussians (using the same start/end points of the linked article from geomstats). Am I missing something ?

More details: I'm using a parametrized cubic spline curve (just as [in here](https://github.com/MachineLearningLifeScience/stochman/blob/ac47a24a649a63ae986c7dc923ae2bb9b7765ed7/stochman/curves.py#L302)), just to give more details about which curve I'm using.

### Trying to make the question more simple

I'm using the following metric (the Fisher metric as linked above) for computing the inner products:

$[ 1/scale, 2/scale ]$ (the matrix is 2x2, this is the diagonal, other elements are zero)

I have 2 parameters (mean, scale), and as you can see, the metric depends only on the scale. These parameters are parametrizing a univariate gaussian distribution (w/ mean and scale), and it is known that this metric induces an hyperbolic geometry (you can understand this better by looking at [this animation](http://caseychu.github.io/normal-distribution-manifold/), just click and drag and you will see the curve geodesic in the parameter space).

[image]

(note that y is my scale and x is mean, the dark black arc line is the geodesic, **but this is not what I'm getting**)

Now, if I minimize $E(\gamma)$ (using gradient descent) to optimize the curve parameters, what I get is a straight line connecting the parameters in the parameter space, while I would expect it to be curved as induced by the metric tensor.

Comment: Try to make your question more self-contained.  You can't necessarily expect the users here to follow your links to understand what you are asking.  Certainly if you fix the endpoints and vary the curve, the extrema of the energy should give geodesics.  I personally don't know what "Fisher metric" is.  Try to include a link to a wiki page if one exists.

Comment: Thank you @MikhailKatz, I added a new section giving more details and showing which metric I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, geodesic can be defined through minimization of the following functional,
$$L=\int_{0}^{1}dt\,\sqrt{g_{ij}(t)\dot{\xi}^i(t)\dot{\xi}^j(t)}$$
and the resulting equation for geodesic is
$$\ddot{\xi}^i(t)+\Gamma_{jk}^i\dot{\xi}^j(t)\dot{\xi}^k(t)=0.$$
Gaussian statistical manifold has the following metric,
$$g_{ij}=\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 2\end{pmatrix}.$$
I have forget that one can also derive the geodesic equation from the energy functional (see related questions and answers below). Let me denote that $\mu$ corresponds to index $1$ and $\sigma$ corresponds to index $2$. Non-zero Christoffel symbols are
$$\Gamma_{11}^{2}=\frac{1}{2\sigma},\,\Gamma_{12}^{1}=-\frac{1}{\sigma},\,\Gamma_{22}^{2}=-\frac{1}{\sigma}.$$
Equations for geodesic become
$$\frac{d^2\mu}{ds^2}-\frac{2}{\sigma}\frac{d\mu}{ds}\frac{d\sigma}{ds}=0, \frac{d^2\sigma}{ds^2}+\frac{1}{2\sigma}\left(\frac{d\mu}{ds}\right)^2-\left(\frac{d\sigma}{ds}\right)^2=0.$$
After some derivations, I find
$$\pm d\mu=\pm\frac{A\sqrt{2}\sigma\,d\sigma}{\sqrt{1-A^2\sigma^2}}.$$
Integrating both sides, I finally write
$$\pm \mu \pm A\sqrt{2}\int\frac{d\sigma\,\sigma}{\sqrt{1-A^2\sigma^2}}=B,$$
where $A$ and $B$ are some constants. Further integration is easy and then you  can check that this equation defines the arc (or vertical line) in $(\mu,\sigma)$-plane.

Some fun: one can consider the gradient flow on Guassian statistical manifold,
$$\frac{d\theta}{dt}=-g^{-1}\frac{\partial\psi(\theta)}{\partial\theta},$$
where $\theta=(\theta_1,\theta_2)$, $\theta_1=\mu/\sigma^2$, $\theta_2=-(2\sigma)^{-2}$ are so-called canonical variables and $\psi(\theta)=\mu^2/(2\sigma^2)+\ln(\sigma\sqrt{2\pi})$ is potential function. Here $g$ denotes metric in $(\theta_1,\theta_2)$ variables and $g^{-1}$ corresponds to inverse metric. This gradient flow can be associated with dynamical system (in left hand side we haver derivatives, $\dot{\theta}_1$ & $\dot{\theta}_2$). It is funny that the following function
$$H=\frac{1}{\theta_1}+\frac{\theta_1}{2\theta_2}$$
can be considered as integral of motion, roughly speaking "Hamiltonian". If one represents $H=PQ$, where $P$ and $Q$ are canonical variables in Hamilton mechanics sense, the system reduces to
$$\dot{Q}=-\frac{\partial H}{\partial P},\,\dot{P}=+\frac{\partial H}{\partial Q}.$$
In $(\mu,\sigma)$-variables, we have
$$\dot{\mu}=-\mu,\quad \dot{\sigma}=-\frac{\sigma^2+\mu^2}{2\sigma}$$
and it defines a family of arcs, parametrized by $H$,
$$\left(\mu(t)-\frac{H}{2}\right)^2+\sigma(t)^2=\left(\frac{H}{2}\right)^2.$$

To sum up,

1. Is the energy function at the very first line in you question correct? May be square root is missed?
2. Gaussian distribution is the exponential distribution and its metric can be computed as Hessian of potential function. You can consider the gradient flow of potential function in order to proove that geodesics are arcs.
3. Naively, I do not see the problem with trappin in local minima. It seems that double check of the code is needed.

**References:**

1. "Information geometry and its applications", S. Amari
2. "On Finding Geodesic Equation of Normal Distribution and Gaussian Curvature", Willian W. S.Chen, 10.4236/am.2017.89098
3. "Completely integrable gradient systems on the manifolds of Gaussian and multinomial distributions", Y. Nakamura, 10.1007/BF03167571

**May be helpful:**

1. [Critical curves of energy functional](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2270622/critical-curves-of-the-energy-functional-are-geodesics)
2. [Finsler geodesic equations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4321675/deriving-finsler-geodesic-equations-from-the-energy-functional)

**P.S.: how we can help you, if you compute everything numerically and provides only pieces of expressions?**

Comment: Thank you for the answer Artem. You asked about the square root missing, but in your case I think you are using the length and not the energy, correct ? As far as I know we don't have the square root in the energy, or am I missing something ? As far as I can see from your answer, my metric tensor is correct, so I think that the issue might be in optimization of E that is getting trapped into a minima that is a straight line instead of converging to an arc. I will accept your answer as you showed the geodesic derivation as well and will keep debugging my problem. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Tarantula , I have forget about the geodesic equation via the energy functional minimization. My last guess is that something wrong in steepest descent, may be with the gradient operator (?). You can try to check Frank Nielsen papers, he writes a lot about the Fisher-Rao distance and so on

Answer (score 2):

I assume *scale* is the *variance*.

You have the metric wrong: it should have been $\text{diag}(1/\nu, 1/2\nu^2)$ where $\nu$ is the scale/variance, ie
$$
g_{\mu\mu}=\frac{1}{\nu},\; g_{\mu\nu}=0,\; g_{\nu\nu}=\frac{1}{2\nu^2}.
$$

That said, I suspect you might also have some problem with finding the geodesics as the $\text{diag}(1/\nu, 2/\nu)$ metric should not result in horizontal lines being geodesic.

A last thing, I suspect that in order to get half-circles as geodesics, you need to use parameters $(\mu,\sigma)$, ie standard deviation instead of scale/variance.

Comment: Thanks, but it seems the problem is the same with this metric as well. I'm pretty sure the metric seems to be the issue because if I use a simple squared distance to origin (https://github.com/MachineLearningLifeScience/stochman/tree/master#stochmanmanifold-interface-for-working-with-riemannian-manifolds) it starts to show curved geodesics.

Comment: @Tarantula If you get horizontal lines as geodesics, there's something wrong with computing the geodesics. You can try plugging in the Poincare metric, $diag(1/y^2,1/y^2)$ for coordinates $(x,y)$, which should give you hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: I will check with the Poincare metric to see what happens. I was wondering if that could be related to multiple minima in the energy minimization, but not sure. However I do get curved geometry if I use the metric I mentioned earlier (square distance), that's why I think the metric is the issue.